# How to make php output like this:

Tags: php

Original text:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCa3Zrd4NkjglMUr3tCa7gLaru2
9Usz5Vpr+k42ADAKrcFjxS/iKgwdBVXhwziWkDaePnDXgmlg5IrxZvJHoyOmIyku
Z1e6guSGGAEPdEEGojOuW9vXe1z1x+HK1u0q328NO4Aezx8QFOmofzSGw+q3svjr
hEiCqWLAcMuOPLK1RwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I want to make it like this:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCa3Zrd4NkjglMUr3tCa7gLaru2\
9Usz5Vpr+k42ADAKrcFjxS/iKgwdBVXhwziWkDaePnDXgmlg5IrxZvJHoyOmIyku\
Z1e6guSGGAEPdEEGojOuW9vXe1z1x+HK1u0q328NO4Aezx8QFOmofzSGw+q3svjr\
hEiCqWLAcMuOPLK1RwIDAQAB\
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I tried to use

```
$publickey=str_replace("\n", "\\\n", $publickey);
```

But the output is like this:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
\
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDOyHkuH6cs4+c2p+7+IbCBCagp
\
jRd5TYpFa2Qxk/kGCNOwaA0CpCOYvTcK0VbpsQ0ajt9yvN4NraX2Spb9fT5atzi1
\
NRqj9uOPSGKD2pTpwzGsytT5TAsBFapMzQn6lJHALOAr4l4jsqkwCO4GgaQiuiIw
\
0KnDqrWB3QUpssHeoQIDAQAB
\
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Can anyone tell me why the output is like this? I used "echo" commend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I found the answer. There is a "\r" when using the Windows OS. The problem solved.